# Don't understand why this class is considered as abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, abstract-class

I have the following classes:

EuropeanOption.h

```
#pragma once

class OptionPricer;

class EuropeanOption
{
protected:

    double dividend;

    double strike;

    double vol;

    double maturity;

    double spot;

public:
    EuropeanOption(void);

    virtual ~EuropeanOption(void);

    virtual double price(double rate, const OptionPricer& optionPricer) const = 0;

    virtual short getSign() const =0;

    double getDividend() const;
    double getStrike() const;
    double getVol () const;
    double getMaturity() const;
    double getSpot() const;


    void setDividend(double dividend_);
    void setStrike(double strike_);
    void setVol(double vol_);
    void setMaturity(double maturity_);
    void setSpot(double spot_);
};
```

EuropeanOption.cpp

```
#include "OptionPricer.h"
#include "EuropeanOption.h"


EuropeanOption::EuropeanOption(void)
{
}


EuropeanOption::~EuropeanOption(void)
{
}


double EuropeanOption::getDividend() const
{
    return dividend;
}

double EuropeanOption::getMaturity() const
{
    return maturity;
}

double EuropeanOption::getStrike() const
{
    return strike;
}

double EuropeanOption::getSpot() const 
{
    return spot;
}

double EuropeanOption::getVol() const
{
    return vol;
}


void EuropeanOption::setDividend(double dividend_)
{
    dividend = dividend_;
}

void EuropeanOption::setMaturity(double maturity_)
{
    maturity = maturity_;
}

void EuropeanOption::setSpot(double spot_)
{
    spot = spot_;
}

void EuropeanOption::setVol(double vol_)
{
    vol = vol_;
}

void EuropeanOption::setStrike(double strike_)
{
    strike = strike_;
}
```

EuropeanCall.h

```
#pragma once

    #include "EuropeanOption.h"

    class EuropeanCall :
        public EuropeanOption
    {

    public:
        EuropeanCall(void);
        EuropeanCall(double spot_, double strike_, double maturity_, double vol_, double dividend_ = 0);

        ~EuropeanCall(void);

        short getSign() const;
        double price(const OptionPricer& optionPricer, double rate) const;
    }

;
```

EuropeanCall.cpp

```
#include "EuropeanCall.h"
#include "OptionPricer.h"
#include <cstdlib>


EuropeanCall::EuropeanCall(void)
{
}


EuropeanCall::EuropeanCall(double spot_, double strike_, double maturity_, double vol_, double dividend_)
{
    spot = spot_;
    strike = strike_;
    maturity = maturity_;
    vol = vol_;
    dividend = dividend_;
}

EuropeanCall::~EuropeanCall(void)
{
}

short EuropeanCall::getSign() const
{
    return 1;
}



double EuropeanCall::price(const OptionPricer& optionPricer, double rate) const
{
    return optionPricer.computePrice(*this, rate);
}
```

OptionPricer.h

```
#pragma once
#include "EuropeanOption.h"

class OptionPricer
{
public:
    OptionPricer(void);

    virtual double computePrice(const EuropeanOption& option, double rate) const =0;
    virtual ~OptionPricer(void);
};
```

OptionPricer.cpp

```
#include "OptionPricer.h"


OptionPricer::OptionPricer(void)
{
}


OptionPricer::~OptionPricer(void)
{
}
```

In my main function, when trying to instanciate an EuropeanCall like this:

```
EuropeanCall myCall(spot,strike,maturity,vol);
```

I get this error message:
object of abstract class type "EuropeanCall" is not allowed

I don't understand why the compiler considers EuropeanCall as an abstract class. Some help please?

Comment: Have you heard of [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared:

```
virtual double price(double rate, const OptionPricer& optionPricer) const = 0;
```

in your base class but got the parameters the wrong way round in your derived class:

```
double price(const OptionPricer& optionPricer, double rate) const;
```

This is not considered an override.

> If some member function vf is declared as virtual in a class Base, and
>   some class Derived, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from
>   Base, has a declaration for member function with the same
>
> name
>
> **parameter type list** (but not the return type)
>
> cv-qualifiers
>
> ref-qualifiers
>
> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or
>   not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and overrides
>   Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its
>   declaration).

Since C++11 you can use the [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier to ensure that a function is indeed virtual and is overriding a virtual function from the base class.

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo();
    void bar();
};

struct B : A
{
    void foo() const override; // Error: B::foo does not override A::foo
                               // (signature mismatch)
    void foo() override; // OK: B::foo overrides A::foo
    void bar() override; // Error: A::bar is not virtual
};
```

Comment: Maybe a good opportunity to mention the `override` keyword that is meant to help fix this kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
virtual double price(double rate, const OptionPricer& optionPricer) const = 0;
```

Is pure virtual function, thus the classes are abstract. You cannot instantiate on instance of a class with a pure virtual function.

Your attempted override does not match this function signature;

```
double price(const OptionPricer& optionPricer, double rate) const;
```

The order of the parameters matter. To catch issues such as this, you can use the `override` specifier and the compiler will check that the function is overriding.

```
double price(const OptionPricer& optionPricer, double rate) const override;
// The override above will cause a compiler error.
```